# jquery jerky animation on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, scroll

I'm trying to implement a simple animation of a logo panel on top of the page scaling when scrolling past a certain point and up if it's scrolled back up. I used jquery's `.animate()` function to change some css parameters. I also use `.stop()` function to break scrolling listener so the whole animation works with no lag.

It's almost there, but I noticed there is some jerky lag happening during the animation. For example when I scroll down it scales down, but not all the way, just slightly and in a second jumps to the full scaled down position. The same happens on scrolling up - it scales halfway or even pauses slightly several times before scaling back up. What do you think could cause that?

Here is my code:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var animScroll;
        $(window).scroll(function() {

            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 700) {
                animScroll = true;
                $('#menu').stop().animate({height: '50px'}, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 400
                });

                $('#toplogo').stop().animate({width: '150px'}, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 400
                });

            } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 700) {
                $('#menu').stop().animate({height: '85px'}, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 400
                });

                $('#toplogo').stop().animate({width: '300px'}, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: 400
                });
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery is not the fastest when it comes to animation. Below I used CSS. Please note I changed the flipping point at 300 pixels.

```js
(function($) {


  $(document).ready(function() {
    var animScroll;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {

        $('#toplogo').addClass("smaller");


      } else if ($(this).scrollTop() < 300) {

        $('#toplogo').removeClass("smaller");

      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
}

#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

#toplogo {
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#toplogo.smaller {
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <img id="toplogo" src="http://placehold.it/200">
  </div>
</div>
```